# picking jQuery 1.9 or 2.0 using JavaScript and Require.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, requirejs

jQuery 2.0 is increasingly mature: http://blog.jquery.com/2013/03/01/jquery-2-0-beta-2-released/

jQuery 2.0 breaks compatibility with older browsers, so one must know when to stay with jQuery 1.9. The recommended approach is to use IE's conditional comments:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
    <script src="jquery-2.0.0b2.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

- current web development best-practice suggests that we should be avoiding browser-sniffing or user agent string parsing, but isn't this sort of what conditional comments are?
- does jQuery 2.0 only break compatibility with older Internet Explorer? or are there other browsers that will be worse off in 2.0?
- if this affects more than just Internet Explorer (which is the only place conditional comments work), then what strategy should we use for selecting the best jQuery?
- is there a globally-accessible value/object/function/etc in the JavaScript environment whose presence can be used to signal compatibility with jQuery 2.0 (e.g. a feature-detect)?

### main question

My projects currently use Require.JS to modularise my code. My code currently loads jQuery only when it encounters the first section that requires it.

**What is the best way to load the correct version of jQuery using Require.JS?**

I'm currently considering:

- using the IE conditional comments before I load Require.JS, then "defining" jQuery manually afterwards
- using a JS feature-detect in the code that sets Require.JS's paths (before anything require's jQuery) setting the path to 1.9 or 2.0 as appropriate (my preferred method)
- always using 1.9 no matter what (the safest and most boring approach)

Comment: conditional comments can't be spoofed like user-agents.

Comment: I read that recommendation and I don't get it, as IE10 doesn't support conditional comments.

Comment: IE10 doesn't support conditional comments, thus it reads it the same as Chrome or Firefox would...ignoring the first comment (as it looks like a comment) and still reading the second script tag.

Comment: Yeah, I initially had the same mental hurdle. Having very infrequently relied on conditional comments, I actually thought that non-IE would get nothing. :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Adaptation of niaccurshi's answer to AMD spec.

```
// Do this before your first use of jQuery.

var pathToJQuery
if('querySelector' in document
    && 'localStorage' in window
    && 'addEventListener' in window) {
    pathToJQuery = '//cdn/jQuery2.0'
} else {
    pathToJQuery = '//cdn/jQuery1.9'
}

require.configure({'paths':{
    'jquery': pathToJQuery
}})

require(['jquery'], function($){ /* you get the one you need here */ })
```

Answer (score 6):

There is actually a more elegant solution, it's being used by the `BBC` for their responsive news website.

It essentially detects browsers considered to be `new`, and thus would be compatible with `jQuery 2.0+`, and therefore leaves everything else as an `old` browser. You may be able to replicate this with `Require.js`, but the reality is you don't need to...

```
if(querySelector in document
    && localStorage in window
    && addEventListener in window) {
    //Add jQuery 2.0+
} else {
    //Add jQuery 1.9.0+
}

//This is intended to be a flag that can be checked against to see if the jQuery library has been loaded into the browser.
var jQueryVersion = 0;
function jQueryRunning(ver) {
    //This could be "true", or could be a version number, it's largely down to your own system needs!
    jQueryVersion = ver;
}
```

**Source:** [link](http://responsivenews.co.uk/post/18948466399/cutting-the-mustard)

You should add a callback function to each of the scripts for `jQuery`, that calls `jQueryRunning` with the parameter equal to it's version number, this may help you decide on further functions to run down the line, and has the benefit of letting you know when the jQuery code has been embedded `(just in case the connection is slow and it takes a while to download)`.

If using `Require.js` this may not be something you want to be concerned about!

I say this is a elegant solution because you're quite right, the issue isn't only old versions of `IE`, it's also older versions of `Firefox (before 3.5)` and old mobile browsers (if they even deal with javascript!)

Comment: I'll probably skip the "localStorage" bit (I assume that has nothing to do with jQuery). So IE8 has querySelector (from the Selectors API) but it doesn't have addEventListener (from DOM Level 2). Looks like this is a nice browser-neutral way of testing this. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, as the article says it's more use if you intend to use it. Though I would say it's a good practice, and doesn't add any performance impact to your code, so for "future proofing" I would personally leave it in :) No problem though.

Comment: Looks cool. Is there a reason for not using `$.fn.jquery` for discovering which jQuery version is running?

Comment: No reason at all, you could probably pass that in to the variable, or just continue to use it as a direct reference. The main reason is to provide you with a way of knowing that the jquery library has loaded from it's dynamic inclusion.

Comment: OK. Also, (assuming the code above to be in the global namespace) I can't see why you would want to overwrite the `jQuery` member with its own version number. Many plugins and some folks' code in its entirety rely on the global member `jQuery` being the lib , not the version number. Or am I missing the point?

Comment: It's my bad for choosing "jQuery" as the variable name in the example, which is only intended to be a rough example of dealing with the load lag outside of Require.js. I don't tend to use the jQuery.method() version over the $.method() version, so it didn't even dawn on me it would be a clash ;)

Comment: To clarify, I'm considering the if-else part of this the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately the source link broke by now: The new one is without blog subdomain: http://responsivenews.co.uk/post/18948466399/cutting-the-mustard