# Picking jQuery 1.9 or 2.0 using JavaScript and Require.JS when optimizing code

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I was facing issues after upgrading to jQuery 2.0 My application stopped working on IE8 and less. The application currently use Require.JS to modularise my code.

I found a very nice solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213439/picking-jquery-1-9-or-2-0-using-javascript-and-require-js) for conditional check of the browser. But my application also uses optimisation described [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) for minifying the code. So I have an app.build.js which looks like the following:

```
({
appDir:         '../',
baseUrl:        'js/',
dir:            '../../v3-build',
locale:         'en-us',
paths: {
    'modernizr':                'libs/modernizr-2.5.3',
    'jQuery':                   'libs/jquery/jquery-2.0.0',
    'underscore':               'libs/underscore-1.4.4',
    'backbone':                 'libs/backbone-0.9.9',
    'bootstrap':                'libs/bootstrap/bootstrap'        

    // Application - bootstrap for frontend app
    'application':              'application'
},
shim: {
    'jQuery': {
        exports:                '$'
    },

    'underscore': {
        deps:                   ['jQuery'],
        exports:                '_'
    },

    'backbone': {
        deps:                   ['jQuery', 'underscore'],
        exports:                'Backbone'
    },

    'application':              ['jQuery']
},
optimize:                   'uglify2',
modules:        [
    {
        name:       'main'
    }
]
```

})

Now how do I add check for jquery path here?

Comment: Why don't you just use jQuery 1.9 so you get the IE support you require? It makes no sense to ensure the application runs against multiple versions of assets.

Comment: Yeah I know. This was the first solution that hit me. But just figuring out if there is a way to achieve this

Answer (score 2):

If you want to decide jQuery version at runtime then you cannot include it in the bundle that r.js creates. You will need to tell the optimizer to leave it out by using the special ["empty:" directive](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#empty), for example:

```
paths: {
    jquery: "empty:"
}
```

Not sure you're saving much bandwidth for all this trouble, but I guess if you give them a CDN path at runtime that should help.